# Push Notification for Chrome browser extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, push-notification, notifications

I built this Chrome browser extension plugin and can't figure out if there is a way to receive a server message from my Backend service in the plugin pretty much like the push notification for iOS.

e.g. notifying the user an event (from the backend) has happened and display this message in the plugin

I spent time looking into Chrome extension's documentation.  They don't seem to have API similar to push notification for the Chrome extension.

Is there any other way do achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm

Comment: thank you @wOxxOm  this is what I am looking for